# Pandas duration groupby - Start group-range with defined value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to group a data set of travel duration with 5 minutes interval, starting from 0 to inf. How may I do that?

My sample dataFrame looks like:

```
    Duration
0   00:01:37
1   00:18:19
2   00:22:03
3   00:41:07
4   00:11:54
5   00:21:34
```

I have used this code: `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Duration', freq='5T')]).size()`

And I have found following result:

```
Duration
00:01:37    1
00:06:37    0
00:11:37    1
00:16:37    2
00:21:37    1
00:26:37    0
00:31:37    0
00:36:37    1
00:41:37    0
Freq: 5T, dtype: int64
```

My expected result is:

```
Duration    Counts
00:00:00    0
00:05:00    1
00:10:00    0
00:15:00    1
00:20:00    1
........    ...
```

My expectation is the index will start from `00:00:00` instead of `00:01:37`.

Or, showing bins will also work for me, I mean:

```
Duration   Counts
0-5        1
5-10       0
10-15      1
15-20      1
20-25      2
........    ...
```

I need your help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to roud off your time to lower 5th minute. Then simply count it.
I suppose this is what you are looking for -

```
def round_to_5min(t):
    """ This function rounds a timedelta timestamp to the nearest 5-min mark"""
    t = datetime.datetime(1991,2,13, t.hour, t.minute - t.minute%5, 0)
    return t

data['new_col'] = data.Duration.map(round_to_5min).dt.time
```

Comment: I got this: AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'hour'

Anyway, thanks. I have solved the problem by ```pd.cut```

Comment: if you find it correct you can accept it as an answer to the question